# Get server timezone In PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, timezone

My client needs a system report his plugin running server details, It means I have to get SERVER timezone. Working with Wordpress.
Tried on this, But this not working on every server.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone(ini_get('date.timezone')));
```

This gives me a fatal error on some servers, 
Got any common function to get server timezone? 
*Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.*

Comment: check out your PHP version first.

Comment: Then you have to check customer's PHP version using php_info()

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$timeZone = $date->getTimezone();
echo $timeZone->getName();
```

Answer (score 14):

Kindly refer following  link
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_default_timezone_get.asp

```
    <?php
      echo date_default_timezone_get();
    ?>
```

The date_default_timezone_get() function returns the current default timezone used by all date/time functions in the script.

Comment: this gives me UTC. But UTC is a time standard, not a time zone

Comment: It doesn't return the **'default'** time zone. It returns the **'current default'** time zone. If you or someone else in your code stream has set the time zone away from the system one then you'll get that.
`code`
php > echo date_default_timezone_get();
Pacific/Auckland
php > date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
php > echo date_default_timezone_get();
UTC
php >
`code`

Comment: To dodge the error this function yields, place `@` in front of the function name... so `date_default_timezone_set(@date_default_timezone_get());`

Comment: @Darksymphony UTC is a timezone in PHP. You can see a complete list of supported timezones by your version of PHP using this command: `DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers()`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set();
if (date_default_timezone_get()) 
{
    echo 'date_default_timezone_set: ' . date_default_timezone_get() . '<br />';
}
if (ini_get('date.timezone')) 
{
    echo 'date.timezone: ' . ini_get('date.timezone');
}?>
```

this code will help you.

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set()` hiccup an error, Seems this need a parameter. currently not given.

Answer (score 0):

Everything mentioned so far gives you the PHP default timezone, which may be set in php.ini or overridden somewhere in the code. If you are looking for the SERVER timezone, here is the solution:

```
$timezone = $_SERVER['TZ'] ??
    (file_get_contents('/etc/timezone') ?: file_get_contents('/etc/localtime'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Check with below code:

```
$datetime = new DateTime();

$datetime_zone = $datetime->getTimezone();

echo $timeZone->datetime_zone();
```

Answer (score -10):

get some help from python. you can get server timezone offset with python.

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
print strftime("%z", gmtime())
```

run the python code in php with exec

```
$tz_offset = exec("python tz.py");
```