# Is there a way to find the hosted server timezone abbreviation in php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to parse the Server's timezone abbreviation in PHP. I couldn't find a dynamic way to do that.

My application is hosted in Different parts of Australia and so we can set the timezone name manually. So, the timezone may include `Australia/Sydney,` `Australia\Melbourne` etc.

So, my target is to fetch the timezone abbreviation like `Australia/Sydney,` `Australia\Melbourne` from the server time in PHP.

Please help.

Comment: Official Documentation : [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php)

Comment: Like this? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429837/ddg#37430083

Comment: If you work with custom timezones you propably can get value with ini_get('date.timezone');

Comment: @user1138 No. It will just return the `UTC` instead of the abbreviation.

Comment: @KenLee Its will return the 'UTC`

Comment: If the server is running on UTC, it is not possible to determine what time zone/location the server is in.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch current timezone setting of the PHP application(may be set by `php.ini` or `date_default_timezone_set()`), you can use `date_default_timezone_get()`

```
$ php -r 'var_dump(date_default_timezone_get());'
string(16) "America/New_York"
```

If "UTC" is returned, it means currently your PHP application is set to use UTC as default timezone. You may need to change your php.ini setting.

---

Please note that the right answer to the following questions are all different:

- Current timezone setting of the PHP application
- Current timezone setting of the server that runs the PHP application
- Current timezone of where the server is located(physically)
- Current timezone of where your user is located(physically)

`date_default_timezone_get()` is the answer to the first question. Depends on your application needs, this may or may not be the right way to do it.

Comment: Even though the server is set to use `UTC`, we should be able to convert it back to GMT from the timestamp.
So, I am expecting a way to make the timezone abbreviation from the server time.